# urlopen error while updating url with variable

Tags: python, pandas, variables, urllib

I am trying to update the url with keywords from another file and read the contents of the url but it is throwing error

```
f = open('myfile.txt')
for line in iter(f):
    id = line.strip('\n')
    url_sell = 'https://example.com/getmarketsummary?market='+str(id)
    df = pd.read_json(url_sell, orient='columns')
```

Below is the error

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error no host given>
```

Comment: could you print `id` to check what value throw an error ?

Answer (score 0):

Use try, excep to debug.

```
for line in iter(f):
    id = line.strip('\n')
    try:
        url_sell = 'https://example.com/getmarketsummary?market='+str(id)
    except:
        return id
```